# a categorical proof for split short exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

It is well known that,in the category of $R$ modules if we have a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow0$ the two following are equivalent(let denote for convenience $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $h:B\rightarrow C$):

$1)$There exists a morphism $g:B\rightarrow A$ such that $g \circ f=Id_{A}$

$2)$There exists an isomorphism between $B$ and the direct sum of $A$ and $C$

I was wondering if we could prove this result for arbitrary abelian categories.I tried to ''reproduce the proof'' in a categorical manner but i am stuck.Any help?

Comment: To be more precise, the second condition should be that there exists an isomorphism between the sequence $0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$ and the sequence $0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow A \oplus C \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$ with the maps in the latter sequence being the canonical inclusion and projection.

Comment: This property is known as the splitting lemma. A proof can be found in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: Yes but this proof is for abelian groups,i need an element-free proof of this lemma @pigeon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as [paul blart math cop](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/571438/paul-blart-math-cop) noted in the comments, 2) should be that there exists an isomorphism between the *sequences* $$0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{h} C \to 0$$ and $$0 \to A \to A \oplus C \to C \to 0.$$

It is clear that 2) implies 1), because finite products and finite sums coincide in abelian categories.

So assume that there is a morphism $g: B \to A$ with $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$. This allows us to define a morphism $g \oplus h: B \to A \oplus C$. If we use the identity maps on $A$ and $C$, this defines in fact a morphism of the two short exact sequences above, using the assumption $gf = \operatorname{id}_A$. By the 5-lemma, $g \oplus h$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You've done the thing that needs to be done, but I was hoping you would explain why the diagram commutes. In the category of Abelian groups, or in the category of $R$-modules, this is pretty trivial. I was hoping you would show why this is the case in an arbitrary Abelian category. I believe one of the squares will require slightly more work than the other three.

Comment: Thank you @red_trumpet , i actually didn't think that we would get the desired isomorphism in that way.